# Can a model have itself as a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am doing a coding project in rails. I have a user model, and I want to add a "spouse_id" to it (which would reference other users). Can a model reference itself in a foreign key?

Comment: What is the data store, for those of us not familiar with Rails?  In some data stores, joins of any kind are problematic, and Rails is not the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I am storing the data in a database (sqlite3 in dev; postgres in prod)

Comment: Then the answer is "of course."  It's called a self-join.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey, I'm still new at this, never heard of a self-join. Now that I know what to look for: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: Also called a Self-referencing table.

Comment: [self referencing tables, good or bad?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177853/self-referencing-tables-good-or-bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments:

> Then the answer is "of course." It's called a self-join.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for the [how-to in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).